# jQuery find() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Code

```
var page = '<h1>Hello!</h1><p>FOO</p><span class="username">this is ur name</span><p>sample text</p>';
```

when I alert `$(page).html()` i get Hello! and when I wrap the contents of the page in a div and alert `$(page).html()` I get the whole html contents.

What I am trying to accomplish here is I have a page string with html template and I am trying to find a class `username` in it and i am getting `null`.

I am confused with this happens

Here is a small fiddle of the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/6TSuq/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `$(page)` you construct a jQuery object which contains 4 elements; for each of the HTMLElements that aren't nested in your string.

```
console.log($(page).map(function () {
   return this.nodeName;  
}).toArray());

// ["H1", "P", "SPAN", "P"]
```

​
`html()` returns the `innerHTML` of the **first** element in this jQuery object; which is why you only see "Hello!".

To find the `.username` you should use the `filter()` method, which searches within the jQuery object for elements which match the given selector.

```
alert($(page).filter('.username').text()); // "this is ur name", kthx.
```

See your updated fiddle here; http://jsfiddle.net/6TSuq/15/

Bare in mind that in future, you might have nested elements such as this;

```
var page = "<h1><span class='username'>Foo</span></h1>";
```

In this circumstance, `filter()`ing for `.username` will yeild no results; as the jQuery object `$(page)` does not contain the `.username` element; it contains a `h1`, which has a descendant which is a `.username`. Therefore here you'd need to use;

```
alert($(page).find('.username').text());
```

For reference, see [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find), [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is:

```
var elem = $('<h1>Hello!</h1><p>FOO</p><span class="username">this is ur name</span><p>sample text</p>').filter('.username').get(0);
console.log($(elem).html()); // returns this is ur name
```

**[​jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yYHXr/)**

You need to convert your string to a jQuery object first in order to use any jQuery method on it.